# logstash won't run as a service

Tags: centos7, logstash, systemctl

Ive installed **logstash v6.3.2** via yum on CentOS7. When I start it via `systemctl start logstash` it appears to start properly but then exits almost immediately. There are no (apparent) errors shown.

(journalctl -f)

> [2018-07-26T10:32:58,645][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#"}
>   [2018-07-26T10:32:58,703][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
>   [2018-07-26T10:32:58,941][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
>   [2018-07-26T10:32:59,523][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline has terminated {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#"}

What Ive tried:

(root) `/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash`:
comes up and stays up

(logstash) (same cmd - same result)

I've tried disabling selinux, forcing ownership of **logstash:logstash** anywhere I could find.

**/etc/systemd/system/logstash.service** is 'stock':

```
[Unit]
Description=logstash

[Service]
Type=simple
User=logstash
Group=logstash
# Load env vars from /etc/default/ and /etc/sysconfig/ if they exist.
# Prefixing the path with '-' makes it try to load, but if the file doesn't
# exist, it continues onward.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/logstash
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/logstash
ExecStart=/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash "--path.settings" "/etc/logstash"
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/
Nice=19
LimitNOFILE=16384

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Check what you have in logstash log file.

Comment: Where did you get logstash from?

Comment: Installed via yum per instructions on elastic site

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here was the 'simple.conf' file that used as a test for a module config. It was reading from stdin which would be closed for a service process.

Anyway - when I swapped it out for a sample of a 'metricbeat.conf' it seems to be working ok now.